# how to display values on java form's labels

Tags: java, swing

I was trying to make a salary calculator using java in netbeans. I coded it with the design. When I enter the employee registration number employee's name then the basic salary and allowance values should be displayed in the relevant field in the form. But it seems my code is not working. I can't find what is the error. Please tell me how to solve this matter and show me what is the wrong with this code? I think I did it right. 
            public class SalaryCal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    NameText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    MonText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    OTText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    SalaryText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    DaysText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    AllowText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    AdvText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    NetText = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    jLabel1.setText("Salary Calculator");

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); 
    jLabel3.setText("Employee Name");

    jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); 
    jLabel4.setText("Registration Number");

    jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); 
    jLabel5.setText("No of OT hours");

    jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); 
    jLabel6.setText("No of working hours");

    jLabel7.setText("Basic Salary");

    jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); 
    jLabel8.setText("Allowance");

    jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); /
    jLabel9.setText("Salary Advance");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); 
    jLabel2.setText("Net Salary");

    NameText.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); 
    NameText.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            NameTextActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    MonText.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18));


    SalaryText.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); 

    DaysText.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); 

    AllowText.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); 

    AdvText.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18));

    NetText.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); /

    jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); /
    jButton1.setText("Reset");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jButton2.setText("Calculate");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jButton3.setText("EXIT");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(59, 59, 59)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(NameText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 342, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(MonText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 342, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel9)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(AdvText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 342, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel8)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(AllowText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 342, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel7)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(SalaryText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 342, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 56, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(DaysText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 342, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(OTText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 342, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(34, 34, 34)
                            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 107, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                            .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addComponent(NetText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 342, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
            .addGap(40, 40, 40))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(203, 203, 203))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(28, 28, 28)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(NameText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(MonText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(24, 24, 24)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addComponent(OTText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addComponent(DaysText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(36, 36, 36)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                .addComponent(SalaryText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel8)
                .addComponent(AllowText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLabel9)
                .addComponent(AdvText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(NetText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(27, 27, 27)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addComponent(jButton3))
            .addContainerGap(25, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void NameTextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    System.exit(0);
}                                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    NameText.setText("");
    MonText.setText("");
    OTText.setText("");
    SalaryText.setText("");
    DaysText.setText("");
    AllowText.setText("");
    AdvText.setText("");
    NetText.setText("");


}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    String valueForName;                                                                                                         
    valueForName=NameText.getText().toString();

     MonText.setText(valueForName);

            if (valueForName=="002"){
                NameText.setText("Mr.Samuel Silva");
                SalaryText.setText("65000");
                AllowText.setText("14500");
}
```

Comment: Your code is not compileable. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Gotta show more than that.

Answer (score 1):

If this is all your code you are missing a few things. You are not declaring any of your variable types. For example:

```
jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
```

Should be:

```
JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();
```

Another issue is that a few methods in your class are not called properly. This function:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Needs to be called with a `JFrame` object which it does not seem like you have access to. This could be solved with the below code but you may want it in a different method.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

The `getContentPane()` and `pack()` methods also needs to be called in the same way.

Lastly, when you are calling things like:

```
NameText.setText("Mr.Samuel Silva");
```

You need to make sure that the object is in the correct scope. `jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)` does not have access to variables declared in `initComponents()`.

Answer (score 0):

at line `if (valueForName=="002")` , you must check the equiavanlance with equals method not == operator. This check always return `false`